# GROUP BY on multiple columns

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have a table that looks like the following -

```
  Id     Reference     DateAttribute1    DateAttribute2
  1      MMM005         2011-09-11       2012-09-10 
  2      MMM005         2012-06-13       2012-09-10 
  3      MMM006         2012-08-22       2012-09-10 
  4      MMM006         2012-08-22       2012-09-11
```

I have handle to the id values. I would like to query such that I get the following result

```
  Id     Reference     DateAttribute1    DateAttribute2
  2      MMM005         2012-06-13       2012-09-10 
  4      MMM006         2012-08-22       2012-09-11
```

I would like my result to be grouped by reference and then 'DateAttribute1' and then 'DateAttribute2' as such - `DateAttribute1` has a priority over `DateAttribute2` as you can see above in the result.
How should I write my query to fetch the results in the above manner?

Any solution?

Comment: "DateAttribute1 has a priority over DateAttribute2" Colud you plz explain ?

Comment: Basically, in the case above, if there are two references with the same reference number, then the syem should look at the dateattribute1 to see which has a greater date and if they are same it should look at the dateattribute2 to check which one is greater and then finally return the appropriate row.

Comment: check my query .. that should work

Answer (score 1):

```
select max(id),Reference, min(DateAttribute1),max(DateAttribute2)
group by Reference
```

Comment: I do not think this will yield the result i am looking for.

Comment: Here we are assuming max(id), I cannot assume that in actual scenario. Am I missing something. Basically I would like to query such that it returns the right row with the id.

Comment: You have multiple rows in some time frame how can you get a single id that it will represent all of the rows in the time frame ? It impossible you need to redefine your question probably

Answer (score 1):

```
Try it.....
```

> select  * from (select  * from your_table order by Id desc) as x group
>   by Reference

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select * 
from   your_table t
join (
      select Reference,
             min(DateAttribute1) as DateAttribute1,
             max(DateAttribute2) as DateAttribute2
      from   your_table
      group by  Reference
      )a
on   t.Reference=a.Reference
and  t.DateAttribute1=a.DateAttribute1
and  t.DateAttribute2=a.DateAttribute2
```

Comment: still not getting the right result with the above code.. thanks so much for your reply anyways...am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

assume table name is 'tbl2'

```
    select * from (select * from tbl2 order by REFERENCE,DateAttribute1 desc,
DateAttribute2 desc )  as abc group by reference
```